# Cannot Publish Android APK, An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2015

I cannot publish an APK for Android. I get an unexpected error "Reason: An item with the same key has already been added."

The project is an Xamarin.Forms project with shared PCL library.

I can build and debug the project successfully without errors, but when I turn off the "Use Shared Runtime" option so I can publish the APK, it fails.

The error message comes right after "GetBuiltOutputRecursive target(s))"

I've searched online and found some similar issues where some of the shared projects are referencing the same native libraries, but my project has just the one PCL shared project and the one Android project.

I've checked all Nuget packages and the Portable project and Android project all have the same versions installed.

How can I tell which items it's trying to add twice and what it's adding it to?

Below is the content from the packages.config for the PCL and Android projects...

PCL:
    "Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "SQLitePCL.bundle_green" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "SQLitePCL.raw" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.1.47" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"
    "ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" version="2.1.47" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81"

Android:
    "Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.1.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "SQLitePCL.bundle_green" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "SQLitePCL.plugin.sqlite3.android" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "SQLitePCL.raw" version="0.9.2" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.2.127" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "ZXing.Net.Mobile" version="2.1.47" targetFramework="monoandroid70"
    "ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" version="2.1.47" targetFramework="monoandroid70"

Comment: If possible could you list all libs you included in Android project?

Comment: Wasn't sure the best way to get that to you so I edited the post with the packages of the packages.config flies for each project. Was this what you were asking for?

Comment: sorry I could not reprocude error, might be relate to Android 7.0? (I havn't installed yet). Anyway it's possible to attach MSBuild.exe and catch exceptions, this may give you error details

Answer (score 0):

Just got the same issue, I was able to fix it by deleting `bin` and `obj` folders in the Android project and restarting the archive process.